# How do I efficiently get the object in an array with the lowest attribute in Python?

Tags: python, list

I'm working on a maze solver with A* in python, and I need to find the node with the lowest f score in the openset.

Here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
current = openSet[0]
for n in openSet:
     if n.f < current.f:
          current = n
          bestF = n.f
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but I don't know how. Anyone know?

Comment: openSet is a data structure with an (x, y) coordinate and an attribute "f" that you are looking to minimize?

Comment: You can use `min(openSet, key=lambda n: n.f)`

Comment: If you maintained `openSet` as a heap rather than just a list, you always know where the minimum value is, and can efficiently update it after minor changes (such as removing that minimum value).  There's a built-in `heapq` module that implements this.

Comment: @joe.dinius openSet is a list containing Node objects, each of which have am f value